# How to create audio spectrum in c#

Tags: c#, .net, audio, directshow.net

I want to make an audio player in c# with signal spectrum.

I saw some examples in the net about how to make the player but cant find example about the spectrum.

Anyone can give me a direction please?

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/directshowmediaplayer.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/directshownet.aspx?fid=4377&select=2579548&fr=1#xx0xx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/SoundViewer.aspx?fid=448560&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=2202971) article that shows how to create a visualizer. If you want to perform more advanced actions, you can look at libraries such as [FMOD](http://www.fmod.org/) and [BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/). They can both pretty much display spectrums with a few lines of code. However, if your project is for commercial use, you should read their licenses. 
Alternatively, you can use the open-source [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) library which also makes it easier to display the spectrum. There's sample code included, such as this [SpectrumAnalyser](http://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/74828#597541) class.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to check [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) out.