# Display a graph of wav file c#

Tags: graph, wav, frequency, voice

I need to display a graph of a wav file in C#, where you can see the actual frequencies of the voice in the file while the file is being played.

in C#.

Any ideas?
thanks,
Ofek

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to render audio waveform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451707/how-to-render-audio-waveform)

[How to create audio spectrum in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245450/how-to-create-audio-spectrum-in-c-sharp)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20025/Sound-visualizer-in-C

... others out there also